# Android app to recognize a flower/plant

Tags: android, image-recognition

I am looking for an Android app that would recognize a flower, or plants in general.

A bit like face recognition, but for plants.

It would give the plant's name, and ideally link to the Wikipedia article if there is one.
Ideally free and open source.

[image: Sunflower]

Comment: May I ask the background for that? Is it to build your own catalog – or rather to care for the plants in your garden? What specific requirements should the app have, beside "recognizing plants"? (I don't know such an app by heart, but I'm pretty sure I've seen some a while ago).

Comment: Just recognizing plants. yesterday I had a walk in the forest, and saw a common plant that I could not remember the name of. It could help in such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four years later, such an app has appeared:

PlantNet

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.plantnet

Free. Backed by 4 French research bodies, it recognizes tons of plants, but you must take the picture close enough.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no such application in Play Store as far as I know. I've searched myself for half an hour and couldn't find an application with that concept. You should probably ask/request a android developer to make an app like this in some forums say XDA Developers.
***[Alternative solution]*** - Only a suggestion from my side that you may have already tried. Take the photo of that flower and search for it in Google Images. You need a workable internet connection though to do this.

Comment: +1 Thanks for spending a lot of time searching! I will try your suggestion of Google Search by Image.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - Always happy to help ;) And by the way if my answer satisfied you, mark it as answer.